# Converting matrix like (multiple rows) data into a single row data in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a text file that lists the data in matrix like tabulation. Below shows the data for a 2x2 matrix for 2 cases.

```
  % Cases e11 e12 e21 e22
    1.100000000000000E6    -2.442126570242587E-1   3.206453099773649E-2
                            7.623990950478551E-2  -4.055318707521479E-1  

    1.200000000000000E6    -2.546137875169113E-1   -6.810628140983756E-5  
                           -9.815943463763438E-4   3.378413070932518E-4 
  END
```

And need is to put the data in a single row for each case. So the resulting format looks like this

```
% Cases e11 e12 e21 e22
 1.100000000000000E6    -2.442126570242587E-1   3.206453099773649E-2   7.623990950478551E-2  -4.055318707521479E-1  
 1.200000000000000E6    -2.546137875169113E-1   -6.810628140983756E-5  -9.815943463763438E-4   3.378413070932518E-4

END
```

I know this might be a beginner's level question and may not be appropriate in this forum. But any help or guidance for getting this done using python would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far? Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to best provide us with a minimal but complete example of your problematic code.

Answer (score -1):

file.txt

```
  % Cases e11 e12 e21 e22
    1.100000000000000E6    -2.442126570242587E-1   3.206453099773649E-2
                            7.623990950478551E-2  -4.055318707521479E-1  

    1.200000000000000E6    -2.546137875169113E-1   -6.810628140983756E-5  
                           -9.815943463763438E-4   3.378413070932518E-4 
  END
```

code

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

i = 0
result = []
for row in data:
    if not row:
        continue
    row = row.strip()
    if i == 0:
        row = [row]
    else:
        row = row.split()
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result[i / 2] = result[i / 2] + row
            i += 1
            continue
    result.append(row)
    i += 1

with open('out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    data = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(x) for x in result])
    f.write(data)
```

out.txt

```
% Cases e11 e12 e21 e22
1.100000000000000E6 -2.442126570242587E-1   3.206453099773649E-2    7.623990950478551E-2    -4.055318707521479E-1
1.200000000000000E6 -2.546137875169113E-1   -6.810628140983756E-5   -9.815943463763438E-4   3.378413070932518E-4
END
```